# Merge array of objects into a single object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in this shape;

```js
const objectsArray = [{ projects: [] }, { components: [] }];
```

I want to merge it into a single object like this;

```js
const mergedObject={ projects: [], components: [] }
```

Is there a better way of doing it other than this:

```js
Object.keys(objectArray).map(key=>objectArray[key]).reduce((old,item)=>(
          {...old,...item}
),{})
```

Comment: mergedObject = { ...objectsArray[0], ...objectsArray[1] }

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit simpler:

```
const objectsArray = [{ projects: [1,2,3] }, { components: [4,5,6] }];

let mergedObjects

objectsArray.forEach(obj => mergedObjects = { ...mergedObjects, ...obj})

console.log(mergedObjects)
```